# IOS: NSUserDefaults Can't find settings on device

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I moved some of my apps settings form inside the app to the Settings menu

Everything works fine on the simulator (as usual:D) but when I try to deploy to a device it can't find the settings values in my NSUserDefaults.

In the Settings menu I can see my app and it's settings, but when I run this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize];   
    NSString *loc=[defaults objectForKey:@"currency"];
    NSLog(@"start");
    NSLog(@"--- %@",loc);
    [defaults setObject:loc forKey:@"localisation"];
```

I get :

> 2012-09-17 15:51:08.240 MyApp[259:707] start
>
> 2012-09-17 15:51:08.243 MyApp[259:707] --- (null)

Any Ideas ?

Comment: are you setting the value fro curreny

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? Otherwise, I would try `NSLog(@"%@", defaults);` first, before even NSLogging `loc`.

Comment: Found the issue, if the user hasn't set a value it doesn't appear. how can I set a default from the plist ?

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` has a method `registerDefaults:`.